# How to execute T-SQL Procedure to load data from one machine to another that has sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have two machines , each one contains SQL Server + different instance/database + different IP/port ( as you know )

I want to **load data from  machine A to Machine B** by executing a **T-SQL procedure** on **B**. I use **Windows Authentication** as authentication method.

I read about [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)  but I couldn't execute it successfully .

**Edit:**

I hope to see an exeample of using sp_addlinkedserver with different servers that use    windows authentication ads auth method

Comment: What was unsuccessful when adding the linked server? Was there an error message?

Comment: I cannot get it now , I work on those machines at work ( I'm at home now) , but I know that I don't understand how to authenticate the connection using windows authentication , I hope to see a code that show how to use sp_addlinkserver with different machines + windows auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :-) , it was related to something called **Security Account Delegation** and  **mapping a SQL server login to the linked serve**

for more information read the first answer [from here](http://www.sqlnewsgroups.net/sqlserver/t7447-linked-server-security-login-failed-user.aspx).

TSQL code:

```
-- drop old things 
-- EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin myLinkedServer, null

-- drop old linked server if it is there 
-- EXEC sp_dropserver 'myLinkedServer'

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='myLinkedServer',
                        @srvproduct=N'',
                        @provider='SQLNCLI',
                        @datasrc='10.10.11.13', -- server ip try 10.16.11.13\Your_Instance_Name
                @provstr='User ID=testuser;password=Aa123456' -- you can add Integrated Security=SSPI;


-- debugging to check if the linked server is created or not 
select * from sys.servers where name = 'myLinkedServer';

-- map a SQL server login to the linked server
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'myLinkedServer', 'false', NULL, 'testuser', 'Aa123456'



-- display some data 
select * from myLinkedServer.[dev_master].[dbo].[attendanceReport]
```

It was tested using SQL Server 2005 + 2008 , and it works successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If sp_addlinkedserver didn't work for you, you might try one of the [Rowset functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187957.aspx) instead.  Specifically, [OpenRowset()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).